# Youtube API Bind live broadcas don't WORK

Tags: php, api, youtube, google-apis-explorer

I have a problem to associate a to youtube transmission from the API

I am following these steps

> 1) I generate a liveBroadcast ---> this return $broadcastID
>
> 2) generate a liveStream   --> this return $streamID
>
> 3) I use this code to asociate (BroadcastID and streamID).

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/bind?id=$broadcastID&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&streamId=$streamID&alt=json&prettyPrint=true");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer $token";
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

But it does not work! It doesn't even return any kind of error or anything.

In the example of the API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/), it works perfect. Can anybody help me?

helpme please!

thanks.